# Event Handler timing issue

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a UDP packet that is broadcast in on a timed interval for GPS position. It is currently broadcast in every 50ms. I have an event handler that is raised on each new packet and then I process the packet and call other code. The broadcast is fairly consistent but can fluctuate a bit as well. Every now and then, either because the packet speeds up OR my code gets hung up, I start having event queue issues/growth because I have not returned to wait for the next event to raise because either the next packet came in too fast or the code being called is not complete.

So, this raises the question, is an event handler the best thing to use here? I think they are which then raises a follow up question, what is the best thing to do to ensure I am ready for the next packet.

I have two thoughts:

1. For issues where the packet comes in too fast, maybe I just drop it and wait for the next one. In other words, if every 50ms is good for me, I set that as a threshold. If a packet comes in after just 30ms, I know it came in too fast and I drop it and wait for the next one so that fluctuations in timing don't affect me. This may be good protection in case something goes haywire and packets are sent every 1ms.
2. For the event handler, maybe the handler just listens and receives the packet but then kicks off a task or thread to do the processing so the event handler can return right away and be ready for the next packet? This is where I am stuck because my mind tells me that you could run in to sync issues where subsequent threads complete faster than previous threads (I say threads but could be tasks or thread pool) and now you are all out of sync which could be problematic for something like GPS location. I am not sure how to implement something like this and deal with potential sync issues.

Help and suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: 50 msec isn't exactly "too fast" on a modern machine.  But your program certainly can and will go catatonic for longer than that once in a while.  You *must* deal with the possibility that you get two packets right after one another with less than one msec in between.  You may have to use the *lock* keyword, depends.  Sane way to go about it is to test your program with a *very* high rate.  Once that works reliably, you'll know it will be fine as well with a 50 msec rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to make the Event Handler do as little work as possible, so that you don't stack up multiple Event Handlers all processing rapidly received packets.

Essentially you seem to have a Queue with incoming messages to the queue being received by an Event Handler - but I suspect you are using the Event Handler to process the packet.

A better design would be to use the Event Handler ONLY to add the incoming packet to a shared Queue instance. You can then have a background thread which Pops the items off the queue and processes them. This means that it wont matter how fast the packets come in.

Comment: I agree with this solution. Make the Eventhandler just put the incoming objects either on a Stack or a Queue. So afterwards feel free to process the Queue. If you need threadsafety i recommend ConcurrentQueue. Cheers

Comment: Thank you all, let me research this and attempt to make a first pass at it. If I have any issues during implementation, I will post again.